# Is there a way to specify a directory for the generated PDF?

Tags: fpdf

I have been working on FPDF for a while and now have some code that is running fine. It generates a PDF without any problem.

Now I want to generate it in a specific location on the server.

I have created a directory within the site structure and called it PDF.

Writing it to the main directory is fine, writing it to this subdirectory does not work.

I have manually written a file to the new location and this works fine.

```
<?php

require('/var/www/html/test/fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//Logo
$pdf->Image('/var/www/html/test/localisation/logo.png',10,6,30);

// $environment holds the main directory location - /var/www/html/test/
// $id is the invoice number

$pdfname = $environment."pdfs/invoice".$id.".pdf"; 

// location shows correctly on screen
print "*** ".$pdfname." ***";

//This is the output statement

$pdf->Output( 'F',$pdfname, true);

?>
```

From this, I would expect the file to write to the pdf directory.

Nothing is being written there.

If pdf directory is removed the file writes correctly into the main directory.

Comment: You said that you could write to the new location but can the user/process that is running the code write to it? This sounds like a permissions problem. I would also make sure that the `$environment` variable contains what you think it should. If you are using Linux `pdf` is not equal to `PDF` which may be part of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
Yes it I am using linux and it I have the correct case for the folder name. Environment has exactly the variables required as it happily writes a pdf to the root directory of the site.
The issue comes when I add a sub directory. I have tried both putting a file in that directory from the server (manually) and the same via a samba share on the network. Both work fine.
Simply the fpdf will generate in to the html directory but not in to html/pdf
Thank you again for replying.

Comment: This still sounds like a permissions problem. When you can write to the directory in your testing are you doing it with/as the same user as the process that is failing? In other words is it failing when trying to do it via a web page or via the command line?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts again Dave. I've not tried via command line but game via GUI and it works fine. Ultimately it's not a huge issue, I'd just like to know why and it would be nice to put all the pdf's somewhere rather than spread all over the root of the site, albeit that they are only going to be temporary files.